# Hexo g -d does not work and Failed to detect version

Tags: hexo

When I try to run `hexo g -d`, the file is not deployed to GitHub, but returns the information in the figure. How can I solve this problem?

```
INFO  Files loaded in 2.56 s
ERROR Failed to detect version info. Error message:
ERROR connect ECONNREFUSED 13.250.168.23:443
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.250.168.23:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem connecting to GitHub, you can try using `ping github.com` to test connectivity.